# subtleCrypto.encrypt() fails in MS Edge but work in Chome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, cryptojs

I am trying to setup a client-side script that will encrypt files <2MB in size to be uploaded to a SharePoint document library. The encryption is necessary for files that contain personnally idenfiable information (PII) such as social security numbers and the like. The code below works perfectly in Google Chrome but fails the .encrypt(...) portion in MS Edge.

Edge will create all the needed results/buffers for the .encrypt(...) function; however, it returns a "Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000b." result. I've seen some other boards talk about Edge and needing to include a "hash" parameter in both the .generateKey(...) and .encrypt(...) scripts; however, that hasn't had any effect on my problem.

What am I missing?

```
file = document.getElementsByName('aFile')[0].files[0]
function encrypt() {
  window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
      name: "AES-GCM",
      length:256,
    },
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
  )
  .then(function(key) {
    pks = key
    crypto.subtle.exportKey( "raw", key)
    .then(function(buf) { 
      newKey = new Int8Array(buf)
      exportedAsBase64 = _arrayBufferToBase64(buf);
    })
    .then(function() {
      reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      reader.onload = function() {
        fileString = reader.result,
          n=fileString.indexOf(";base64,") + 8;
        X = _base64ToArrayBuffer(fileString.substring(n))
        crypto.subtle.encrypt({name: 'AES-GCM', iv: newKey}, pks, X)
        .then( function(buf) {
           newFile = new Int8Array(buf) 
           encrypted = _arrayBufferToBase64(buf);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }); 
      }
    })
  })
}

function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Comment: What you Edge browser version? Please refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) and try to use different algorithms (such as: RSA-OAEP) to encrypt the data. Besides, here is a [public issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7919579/), you could set break point in the JS code, and make sure the encrypted data is not empty.

Comment: Ok, so apparently my organization is still running MS Edge v41.16299.15; which is why I keep throwing an error since the API isn't supported until the most current version of Edge. I guess I'll just have to wait for them to catch up and approve the newest version for use on our systems.